# Spark Streaming map processing same message multipe times

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

My data flow is:

FTP -> NiFi -> Kafka -> Spark Streaming -> Kafka

**NiFi -> Kafka** topic has 3 partitions and I am using 3 executors. Spark Streaming job reads data from Kafka using direct API. Jobs flow is:

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> consumerStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(javaStreamingContext, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, byte[]>Subscribe(CONSUME_TOPICS,
                    kafkaConsumeParams));

JavaDStream<KeyValue<String, byte[]>> messagesStream = consumerStream
            .map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>, KeyValue<String, byte[]>>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public KeyValue<String, byte[]> call(ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> kafkaRecord) throws Exception {
            ...
            LOGGER.info("processing messages with key: " + key);
            return new KeyValue<>(key, valueBytesStream.toByteArray());
        }
    });

messagesStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<KeyValue<String, byte[]>>>() {
    public void call(JavaRDD<KeyValue<String, byte[]>> rdd) throws Exception {
     rdd..foreach(new VoidFunction<KeyValue<String, byte[]>>() {
                    ...
     }
});
```

I have observed that I consume 55 messages whereas 69 messages are produced. 1434 consumed messages produce 1438 messages.

The job works fine in two cases:

1. Make single partition of Kafka topic and use single executor
2. Replace map with mapPartition(...) and rdd.foreach with
   rdd.foreachPartition(...)

In the logs *processing messages with key:* is being repeated 69 times and 1438 times respectively. I am failed to understand this behavior. Can someone please throw some light on this?

Comment: First, Kafka does not have exactly once guarantees. So it's possible to have duplicate data. Though, Confluent announced they will support exactly once semantics in Kafka 0.11. https://www.confluent.io/blog/we-will-say-exactly-confluent-platform-3-3-available-now/  Second, Spark also does not guarantee exactly once for your output. So better do your dedup at the end.

Comment: I have used option 2 by replacing map/foreach with mapPartition/foreachPartition. Service is working fine since then. Looks like multiple partitions/executors don't go well with map and perhaps mapPartition works independently for each partition and we get exactly-once semantics in this way.

Comment: @maasg Can you please explain what's going on?